# How do you use setColumnAttribute with update()?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to strip non-numeric characters on an attribute before saving, but the new value is not saved.

My model looks like this:

```
class Model extends \Eloquent {
    public function setColumnAttribute($value) {
        $value = (int)preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $value);

        return $value;
    }
}
```

That method do run, if I add a `dd($value)` in it, that dumps.

I update the model with this:

```
Model::find($id)->update($attributes);
```

Why doesn't it save the value given from the `setColumnAttribute` method? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By searching on `eloquent mutator` I find out you had to insert it in the `$this->attributes` array instead of returning the value.

```
class Model extends \Eloquent {
    public function setColumnAttribute($value) {
        $value = (int)preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $value);

        $this->attributes['column'] = $value;
    }
}
```